# Separate process is not creating in MS PowerPoint while creating in MS Word and Excel

Tags: powerpoint

We have designed Microsoft Addins for MS PowerPoint 2019 written in VB.net.
There I am trying to create separate process in MS PowerPoint to open a presentation/file using the given below snippet

```
 Dim objPpt As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim objDoc As PowerPoint.Presentation
 objPpt = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
 objDoc = objPpt.Presentations.Open(processFile, False, , True)
 objPpt.Visible = True
```

but it creates threads of Parent file and does not open a file as a separate process where in MS Word I use the given below snippet

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(processFile, , , True, , , , ,, , , , ,, ,)
objWord.Visible = True
```

And it opens the word document as a separate process.

So I need to create separate process for each file/presentation in MS PowerPoint

Can you help in resolving this issue ?

Here are some more information about on which environment I'm working :

**Operating System** : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

**Code Editor** : Visual Studio 2019

**Technology** : Vb.net(.Net Framework 4.8)

**MS Office Version** : 2019(32 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Word and Excel both allow multiple instances of themselves to be created.
PowerPoint does not (other than as the result of an obscure bug).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this information. Can you share any suitable article of Microsoft stating the same?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/use-visual-c-automate-run-program-instance ... scroll down to the NOTES section.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the impact of trying multiple applications of PowerPoint. As per the Microsoft paragraph below it will be sharing the process so painting of Menu bar/Standard bar/Add-ins tabs must be sharing objects so you cannot perform operation independently. Performed operation will going to impact other PPT screen.

Refer Link: [About PowerPoint Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/use-visual-c-automate-run-program-instance)

*Multiple instances of Word (Winword.exe), Excel (Excel.exe), and Microsoft Access (MSAccess.exe) can run simultaneously. **Therefore, these servers are defined as Single Use (Multiple Instances) servers. Only one instance of PowerPoint (Powerpnt.exe) can run at any given time**. Therefore, PowerPoint is a Multiuse (Single Instance) server.*

Also refer screenshot:

[image]